# select hierarchical item using function

Tags: sql, hierarchical-data

I tried to generate Html from table. And to achieve that, I used function.

**TABLE:**

```
LayoutId        LayoutDetailsId ParentId        DetailSyntax    DetailValue
--------------- --------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
2               15              0               table           htmlchild
2               16              15              tbody           htmlchild
2               17              16              tr              htmlchild
2               18              17              th              No.
2               19              17              th              Name
2               20              17              th              Address
2               21              16              tr              htmlchild
2               22              21              td              1
2               23              21              td              Asha
2               24              21              td              Flamboyan Street
2               25              16              tr              htmlchild
2               26              25              td              2
2               27              25              td              Jack
2               28              25              td              Manggo Street
```

note that htmlchild in DetailValue is like "HasChild"

**FUNCTION:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION FnHtmlGenerator(@layoutId BIGINT, @parentId BIGINT = 0, @prevTopLevelHtml VARCHAR(MAX) = '')
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @currentHtml VARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @parentTable TABLE
    (
        layoutDetailsId BIGINT,
        parentId BIGINT,
        syntax VARCHAR(50),
        val VARCHAR(50)
    );

    INSERT INTO @parentTable
    SELECT
        ld.LayoutDetailsId,
        ld.ParentId,
        ld.DetailSyntax,
        ld.DetailValue
    FROM Alert.LayoutDetails ld
    WHERE ld.ParentId = @parentId
    AND ld.LayoutId = @layoutId;

    SELECT
        @currentHtml = '<' + pt.syntax + '>{0}</' + pt.syntax + '>',
        @parentId = pt.layoutDetailsId
    FROM @parentTable pt;

    SELECT
        @prevTopLevelHtml =
        CASE CHARINDEX('{0}', @prevTopLevelHtml)
            WHEN 0 THEN @currentHtml
            ELSE STUFF(@prevTopLevelHtml, CHARINDEX('{0}', @prevTopLevelHtml), 3, @currentHtml)
        END;

    SELECT
        @prevTopLevelHtml =
        CASE
            (SELECT COUNT(0)
            FROM Alert.LayoutDetails ld
            WHERE ld.ParentId = @parentId)
            WHEN 0 THEN @prevTopLevelHtml
            ELSE FnHtmlGenerator(@layoutId, @parentId, @prevTopLevelHtml)
        END;

    RETURN @prevTopLevelHtml;
END
```

**RESULT:**

```
html
---------------------------------------------------
<table><tbody><tr><td>{0}</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

The problem is. My function only trace 1 path. the first `tr` and first `td` even `th` is not traced. How to make it trace all path ?

Answer (score 1):

Because when you call

```
SELECT 
    @currentHtml = '<' + pt.syntax + '>{0}</' + pt.syntax + '>', 
    @parentId = pt.layoutDetailsId 
FROM @parentTable pt;
```

... that returns the last row in the table, and assigns that to the variables, so the path is 2/15/16/25/28

You may want to look at the recursive abilities of common table expressions (eg: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) and/or the Hierarchical data type if your database platform supports it (SQL Server 2008+,)

Comment: could you give a sample. I tried but it's not quite like I imagine